# How to match chunks of textfile-data-lines to categories before printing?

Tags: python, list, loops, printing, text-files

I have a txt-file with data on x different property-listings. In my program.py every line from the txt-file is sorted into a list through readlines(),i.e every list-element contains a line of data from the txt-file, lets call the list "properties". For every property in the txt-file there is for example 4 lines of data:

---

In textfile:

900000

200

50

Streetname1

80000

100

30

Streetname2

Were 90000 (line one in txt-file) is price for property one, 200 is rent and 50 represents square meters and then streetname, then there is an empty line and then new data for property two where the price is 80000 etc.

I want to print the dataelements from the list "properties[]" (each element is a line in from the textfile) to the user, but while adding categories for each data-line through the program (not from the textfile), and then do it for all properties so data for all properties are printed out. The categories are the same for every property, so they match the datalines for every chunk in the txt-file. This is an example on how I have written it for one property:

```
print("\n"+"Price: "+properties[0]
      +"Rent: "+properties[1]
      +"Size: "+properties[2]
      +"Street: "+properties[3])
```

How can I create a formula that goes through all elements, all data in the list "properties" and print them out to the right categories?

I want the output to be:

Price: 900000

Rent: 200

Size: 50

Street: Streetname1

emptyline

Price: 800000

Rent: 100

Size: 30

Street: Steetname2

... then planning to make one side for each block, for each property

Comment: please provide how you want the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a matrix for that and just loop throughout that matrix. For the input you gave I would do something like this

```
    #Open text file
    with open("example.txt","r") as textFile:
        #Read file and break into array of strings
        text = textFile.read().split()
    #Create empty arrays to store the formated text
    matrixOfProperties = []
    properties = []
    #Loop thru strings to format into an array of arrays of properties
    for index in  range(0,len(text)):
        #Apend propertie to the array of properties
        properties.append(text[index])
        '''
        When all the 4 properties where appended to the
        array of properties, appends the array to the
        matrix and clear the array
        '''
        if index%4 == 3:
            matrixOfProperties.append(properties)
            properties = []
    #Loops over the matrix printing all the elements
    for propertie in matrixOfProperties:
        print("\nPrice: "+propertie[0]
          +"\nRent: "+propertie[1]
          +"\nSize: "+propertie[2]
          +"\nStreet: "+propertie[3])
```

input:
900000

200

50

Streetname1

80000

100

30

Streetname2

output:

Price: 900000
Rent: 200
Size: 50
Street: Streetname1

Price: 80000
Rent: 100
Size: 30
Street: Streetname2

Comment: Thank you! How can I make it work if forexample Street: Streetname 2 , i.e a space between streetname and 2.. then I get two strings instead of one in the list..?

Comment: Well you will have to edit your string before printing this will depend on how the txt file is setup and might be a bit harder... if it is setup in your txt file as Streetname2 and you want to print as Streetname 2 use a for to go on that string and add the space. If it i on your text file as Streetname 2 then I would eliminate the blank space between the lines of your input and use .split('\n') instead of .split()

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = open("file.txt", 'r').readlines()
properties = zip(*[x[i::4] for i in range(4)])
param_names = ("Price", "Rent", "Size", "Street")
for property in properties:
    print('\n')
    print('\n'.join(["%s: %s" % k, v for k, v in zip(param_names, property)]))
```